# Vertical ticket feed with Ajax and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to implement a vertical ticker feed of 20 news say. Here I want to have this with below points :

1.) The ticker should display first 5 news at a time. When a user scroll down in the ticket box, he/she can view the others news down to 20th one.

2.) when a user hovers on any news div section, it should display a box in the left side of the news text. Just like as in the case of Facebook ticker. Here what's important is, The box should be displayed well relative to the position of the news div section. If the current position of the news div section is at the bottom of the page then the hover box should be appear at the bottom only. Similarly if the news div position is at the middle of the page, then it should display the hover box at the middle. In a nutshell the hover box should be dynamically adjust its position based on the position of the new div section.

I am facing challenges while developing this so decided to take help from you guys. The main challenge is, while trying to make the ticker box scrollable of fixed height to contain only 5 elements, it is hiding the hover box as well.

Comment: This isn't a question. You're asking us to develop something for you.  Show us what you have developed so far and present us with a specific problem you would like help with.

Comment: @hairmot: I don't want you to develop something, Just a 2-3 liner solution in words would suffice. Please read the whole question where I have mentioned the issue I am facing here

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: show us your existing code

Comment: Regarding point 1. Is this a problem you're facing (i.e. it doesn't do it), or a just a requirement for a feature you haven't started yet? If it's the latter, you need to try and write something and then we can fix it if you have a problem. Regarding point 2. If you have a problem with your code, as you mention regarding hovering, you need to show the relevant part(s) of it then we can fix it.

Comment: @hairmot : I am in a mobile device right now that's why not being able to show the complete code:(

Comment: ok well that's no problem we can wait. We can't really help you without it, though.

Comment: @Adyson : ok here you go. Please check this link where I have shown the code : https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FHYL495LNTHW

Comment: Here I have disabled the overflow-y property as overflow1-y. If you enable it, you will see the left box also would be hidden. Any suggestion how to overcome this?

Comment: @hairmot : please check this : https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FHYL495LNTHW

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve the moving context div would be to render it for every item and show it when the user hovers over the ticker item.

Each item would look like `<div class="a">NEWS 1 <div class="a1">TO THE LEFT (news)</div></div>`

Then you simply set .a1 to `display:none` on load and add

```
.a:hover .a1 {
display:block;
}
```

in your css.

To solve your overflow problem when setting overflow-y to scroll, you can set a margin-left to your list which will expand the overflow-x bounds (and allow your hover over content to display)

[Example here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FHYLU0NPB606)

to get what you're really wanting, you're gonna have to use javascript. You'll need to listen to the onmouseover event for all your ticker items and set the Y position of the content div to match. example here: [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jLPdYX) you'll need to sort updating the content of the div and correct left/right position based on where you want it to show

Comment: thanks for the help but mate the main issues comes when you apply the "overflow-y : scroll" property to the main div and this is what I need to overcome. https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FHYLVVDF4VS6

Comment: please see my updated answer! ( i updated the link too)

Comment: Ahh that's great buddy. Thanks a ton. This is what I am looking for :). Just one more thing: If I hover the bottom most news then major part of the hover box is disappearing. Any idea if this can also be resolved??

Comment: sorry mate but it still does not resolve my issue, you have applied a width of 500px to the container due to which it is Occupying the unnecessary space on the left and I would not be able to use that space. :(

Comment: to get what you're really wanting, you're gonna have to use javascript. You'll need to listen to the onmouseover event for all your ticker items and set the Y position of the content div to match. example here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jLPdYX you'll need to sort updating the content of the div and correct left/right position based on where you want it to show

Comment: Thanks mate. Works perfectly for me :)